# Generate date range in Snowflake

Tags: sql, date, time-series, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-range

I want to create a date range between two timestamps. I saw similar posts and also checked [this](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Generate-gap-free-sequences-of-numbers-and-dates) method. However, still couldn't achieve the expected output below.

Please note that if `ended_at` is NULL, then `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` needs to be taken.

**Example data:**

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 'A' AS id, '2021-05-18 18:30:00'::timestamp AS started_at, '2021-05-19 09:45:00'::timestamp AS ended_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' AS id, '2021-05-24 11:30:40'::timestamp AS started_at, NULL::timestamp AS ended_at
    )
SELECT *
FROM t1
```

**Expected result:**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generate array of spaces with length = datedfiff, split array and flatten to generate rows. Use index as number of days to add to the start date:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 'A' AS id, '2021-05-18 18:30:00'::timestamp AS started_at, '2021-05-19 09:45:00'::timestamp AS ended_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' AS id, '2021-05-24 11:30:40'::timestamp AS started_at, NULL::timestamp AS ended_at
    )
    
SELECT t1.*, dateadd(day, v.index, to_date(t1.started_at)) as date_generated 
FROM t1, 
     lateral flatten (split(space(datediff(day,to_date(t1.started_at), nvl(to_date(t1.ended_at), current_date))),' ')) v
;
```

Result:

```
ID  STARTED_AT              ENDED_AT                DATE_GENERATED
A   2021-05-18 18:30:00.000 2021-05-19 09:45:00.000 2021-05-18
A   2021-05-18 18:30:00.000 2021-05-19 09:45:00.000 2021-05-19
B   2021-05-24 11:30:40.000 null                    2021-05-24
B   2021-05-24 11:30:40.000 null                    2021-05-25
```

Comment: @KadirSenkaya Edited:  row_number is not needed because flatten gives index column

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE if you have a relatively small number of days you need to generate:

```sql
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT
        'A'                              AS id,
        '2021-05-18 18:30:00'::timestamp AS started_at,
        '2021-05-19 09:45:00'::timestamp AS ended_at
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'B'                              AS id,
        '2021-05-24 11:30:40'::timestamp AS started_at,
        NULL::timestamp                  AS ended_at
),
     row_gen (id, started, ended, generated_day) as (
         select
             t1.id id,
             t1.started_at::date started,
             coalesce(t1.ended_at, current_timestamp)::date ended,
             started generated_day
         from t1
         union all
         select
             id,
             started,
             ended,
             dateadd('day', 1, generated_day)
         from row_gen
         where generated_day < ended
     )
SELECT *
FROM row_gen
```

```
+--+----------+----------+-------------+
|ID|STARTED   |ENDED     |GENERATED_DAY|
+--+----------+----------+-------------+
|A |2021-05-18|2021-05-19|2021-05-18   |
|A |2021-05-18|2021-05-19|2021-05-19   |
|B |2021-05-24|2021-05-25|2021-05-24   |
|B |2021-05-24|2021-05-25|2021-05-25   |
+--+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something slightly different from what the o.p. was asking for, but useful for those looking to generate a list of dates in Snowflake SQL.

This uses the [row_number](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number) window function along with [dateadd](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd) and [generator](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator) to increment from a starting date.

```
select
  dateadd(day, row_number() over(order by 1)-1, to_date('2023-04-01')) as seq_date
from
  table(generator(rowcount => 30));
```

...resulting in:

```
SEQ_DATE
2023-04-01
2023-04-02
2023-04-03
...
2023-04-28
2023-04-29
2023-04-30
```

See also: [Lukasz Szozda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70365505/199166) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365384/generate-dates-within-a-range-in-snowflake).