# Generate dates within a range in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in postgres
one of the columns is year which is calculated as :

```
date_part('year',current_date) + generate_series(-2,4)
```

so if I take today's date , the output will be :

| year |
| --- |
| 2021 |
| 2025 |
| 2019 |
| 2024 |
| 2023 |
| 2022 |
| 2020 |

How to achieve the above in snowflake environment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below snowflake community article will give more in depth info about using functions like  SEQ1(),SEQ2(),SEQ4(),SEQ8() and generator functions.

[Generate gap free seq and dates](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Generate-gap-free-sequences-of-numbers-and-dates)

Comment: "OH SNAP! The Page is Not Found"

Answer (score 2):

Using [GENERATOR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator.html) and [DATEADD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html):

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY seq8())-3, current_date) AS y,
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 7));
```

And year only:

```
SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY seq8())-3 AS y,
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 7));
```